# Oracle Apex creating stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to apex and stored procedures. Here is just a simple example procedure i created. But it keeps output "success with a compilation error". Hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_client_info AS
BEGIN
   select CLIENTID from client
END get_client_info
```

Comment: If you're using APEX's SQL Command window to create this, for future reference, you can see object errors in the Object Browser (find your procedure and click the "Error" tab).

Answer (score 0):

semicolons `;`, variable declaration and return by `into` clause are missing. Try the following one :

```
SQL>set serveroutput on;
SQL>CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_client_info AS
   v_CLIENTID client.CLIENTID%type;
BEGIN
   select CLIENTID into v_CLIENTID from client;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_CLIENTID);
END get_client_info; -- no need to use "get_client_info" part here, i mean using "END;" is enough, if you'd like.
/
SQL>exec get_client_info;
```

*or return result value outside :*

```
SQL>CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_client_info( o_CLIENTID out client.CLIENTID%type ) AS
    BEGIN
       select CLIENTID into o_CLIENTID from client;
    END; 
    /
    SQL>var clinfo varchar2;
    SQL>exec get_client_info(:clinfo);
    SQL>print clinfo;
```